# Allowed Memory size exhausted

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have wamp and change configuration in php.ini still show below error while importing zip sql file to database in phpmyadmin

```
Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 69931615 bytes) in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\zip_extension.lib.php
```

I have changed following to php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M

memory_limit = 64M

post_max_size = 120M
```

I have zip file to imort is size of 16.1 MB

Comment: and where's the code?

Comment: The memory limit is not directly related to upload_size and max_post_size. Do you process the zip using PHP?

Comment: Please read the question carefully. problem is that I tried to import the zip sql file in phpmyadmin of wamp and shows the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, change it again.
A 16.1 MB zip may contain a 120MB SQL file. And PHPmyAdmin may want some for itself.

Just set your memory_limit to 512M or try to import files of lesser size.

Another opportunity is to unzip your file manually and then feed it to mysql console app or [Sypex Dumper](http://sypex.net/en/)

Comment: thanks, I was struggling for long time for this error now it's working